# Nesting My Own Frameworks with Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, dependency-management, carthage

I'm having problems trying to realize the following dependency setup between two frameworks and an app, all developed by me:

[image]

1. **Util** containts a bunch of low-level utilities and extensions to `Foundation` types such as `String`, `Date`, etc.
2. **UI** contains a bunch of custom `UIView` and `UIViewController` subclasses, class extensions for `UIColor`, `UIImage`, etc..

The app and each framework has its own repository on GitHub.

---

The **UI** framework is set up to depend on the **Util** framework, using Carthage:

1. The project's **Cartfile** contains a reference to the **Util** repo:

   `github "MyOrganization/Util.git"`
2. Util is listed in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", but **not embedded** (because **UI** is a *framework* project, *not an app*).
3. The *Framework Search Paths* build setting contains `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS` in addition to `$(inherited)`
4. The .gitignore file is configured to ignore the whole `Carthage` directory (not just `/Build`)
5. I am **not** using git submodules, and I don't intend to (I have enough headaches already).

---

If I clone the UI framework and run `carthage update`, Carthage fetches/builds Util and I can embed it manually to build the UI framework.

***So far so good.***

---

But if I clone the **App** framework and run `carthage update`, Carthage fetches the **UI** repo, but it fails to build:

1. The directory `App/Carthage/Checkouts` contains the checked-out copy of the UI project, as expected. However, there is no further Carthage directory for the nested framework (I assume it should be `App/Carthage/Checkouts/UI/Carhage/Checkout/Util`).
2. Navigating to `App/Carthage/Checkouts/UI` opening the workspace there with Xcode and building it also fails, obviously. The reference to `Util.framework` is broken.

From what I've read, Carthage should fetch the recursive dependency; What am I missing here?

I tried adding both framework URLs the the **App** Cartfile, but xcode still fails to build the **UI** framework.

The bottom part of the log pointed to by the carthage output says:

```
/Users/me/Projects/App/code/App/Carthage/Checkouts/UI/code/UI/UI/MyClass.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'Util'

import Util
       ^

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

---

#### Update

I put together a [minimal reproducible example](http://nicolas-miari/NestedFrameworkDemo-A) on GitHub. The app and frameworks make up this dependency graph:

```
A -> B -> C
// (and also A -> C, but that's not relevant now)
```

(C is the app, B and C are frameworks).

When running `carthage update` on the **A** project, it fetches both framework repos, checks out both, starts to build **B** first and fails, just as above (`import` directive).

The checked out copy of **B** has the right Cartfile, along with all the source files, but there is no nested `Carthage/` directory, let alone the necessary copy of **C** within it.

I guess I need to somehow make the build process refer to `A/Carthage/Builds/C.framework` instead of `A/Carthage/Checkouts/B/Carthage/Builds/C.framework`, but don't know how to set up the B project for that to work out...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL, DR:** My UI framework didn't have its Cartfile at the root of the repository, so carthage could not "see" it during the build (even though the file itself was fetched, and stored several directories deeper).

---

As Github user **Sho Ikeda** ([@ikesyo](https://github.com/ikesyo)) kindly pointed out on [this thread/issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/415#issuecomment-380637689) of the Carthage repository, my **intermediate** framework (**UI**, in this case) didn't have its **Cartfile at the root**. Instead, it was more like this:

```
.git
.gitignore
docs/
code/
    UI.workspace
    UI/
        UI.xcodeproj
        Cartfile
        Carthage/
            Build/
            Checkouts/
```

etc., when it needs to be more like this:

```
.git
.gitignore
Cartfile
docs/
code/
    UI.workspace
    UI/
        UI.xcodeproj

Carthage/
    Build/
    Checkouts/
```

I was under the assumption that the Cartfile had to be at the same level as the Xcode project; that is not the case. After moving the Cartfile to the root, and changing my framework project's Build Setting "Framework Search Paths" from:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS
```

to:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/../../Carthage/Build/iOS
```

...in order to account for the move, so that linking against `Util` when building **UI.framework** from its workspace doesn't fail.

Lastly, I ran `carthage update` form my **App** directory, linked the frameworks, etc. as explained in the Carthage GitHub page, and it worked like a charm. I can successfully instantiate classes defined in my Util (innermost) framework from my App's source code (outermost).

Comment: This turned out to be my issue as well. I, like you, had everything under a _Code folder and while this worked perfectly for for everything (including Carthage use), it broke when I tried including my own frameworks as nested dependencies with Carthage. In my case, I didn't need to add/adjust any search paths, since I also moved my Xcode workspace and project to the same root folder, and it worked right away. Moving everything to the root folder worked, thanks so much for this life-saving post!

Comment: @BenStahl Great to know that it was of help.